# Determine interpreter from inside script

Tags: linux, bash, interpreter

I have a script; it needs to use bash's associative arrays (trust me on that one).

It needs to run on normal machines, as well as a certain additional machine that has /bin/bash 3.2.

It works fine if I declare the interpreter to be `/opt/userwriteablefolder/bin/bash4`, the location of bash 4.2 that I put there.. but it then only works on that machine.

I would like to have a test at the beginning of my script that checks what the interpreting shell is, and if it's bash3.2, calls `bash4 $0 $@`.  The problem is that I can't figure out any way to determine what the interpreting shell is.  I would really rather not do a $HOSTNAME based decision, but that will work if necessary (It's also awkward, because it needs to pass a "we've done this already" flag).

For a couple reasons, "Just have two scripts" is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which interpreter is used by looking at `$SHELL`, which contains the full path to the shell executable (ex. `/bin/bash`)

Then, if it is Bash, you can check the Bash version in various ways:

- `${BASH_VERSINFO[*]}` -- an array of version components, e.g. `(4 1 5 1 release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- `${BASH_VERSION}` -- a string version, e.g. `4.1.5(1)-release`
- And of course, `"$0" --version`

Comment: I couldn't make `$0 --version` work, but `$BASH_VERSION` exists.  Despite not being in `printenv`.  I went looking for that.  I dislike environmental variables that `printenv` can't see....

Comment: @zebediah49 It's a shell variable, not an environment variable.  e.g. you can set `foo=bar`, and it will not be in `printenv` unless you `export foo`.

Comment: FWIW this does *not* work if the user is using a different login shell but still running a bash script.

Comment: The remarks about SHELL are completely wrong.  `SHELL` is totally unrelated to the shell that is running the script.  That's like saying that "EDITOR is the full path to the editor that is being run" or "PAGER is the full path of less".   The SHELL environment variable indicates the shell that the user prefers, nothing more.

Comment: @ephemient : The `SHELL` variable is pretty useless, unless you have set up your shell configuration to set this variable properly. When I run a bash subshell from within a zsh shell, `SHELL` is still set to zsh, and vice versa. For bah, `BASH_VERSION` seems to be reliable.

Comment: I downvoted because the first and most prominent line about `$SHELL` is incorrect, as others have noted. `$BASH` points to the currently running interpreter. The `$BASH_VERS*` advice is good, but `$0` will contain the name of the running script, so passing `--version` to it won't help.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an option, depending on how you launch the script:

1. Install bash 4.2 as `/opt/userwriteablefolder/bin/bash`.
2. Use '#!/usr/bin/env bash' as the shebang in your script.
3. Add '/opt/userwriteablefolder/bin' to the front of `PATH` in the environment from which
    your script is called, so that the `bash` there will be used if present, otherwise
    the regular `bash` will be used.

The benefit would be to avoid having to detect the version of bash at runtime, but I realize your setup may not make step 3 desirable.

Comment: There's actually a bit of a benefit to that, though it makes it more user-dependent.  Hence, going with the actual version check.