# How to get script interpreter name inside a script?

Tags: shell, makefile

If I want to know my shell, I can write:

```sh
echo $0
```

Inside a makefile shell, I can type :

```sh
echo $$0
```

How can I do it inside a shell script?

`myscript.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $0 #shows 'myscript.sh' instead of 'bash'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine interpreter from inside script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697076/determine-interpreter-from-inside-script)

Answer (score 0):

The `$0` variable refer to the name used to invoke the command. When a script is invoked with the #! prefix (a.k.a. `shebang`), then $0 will be the name that was used to refer to the script.

When running one of the *sh scripts (bash, sh, dash, ...), there are few ways to find which specific script engine was used. One option is to query the symlink '/proc/$$/exe' which will point to the name of the shell engine. The readlink can be used to query the link

```
ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 owner owner 0 Dec  2 18:21 /proc/8/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
###
S=$(readlink /proc/$$/exe)
echo "Running under $S"
```

Another option, when you only need to tell if you are running under bash, you can use one of the $BASH variables: $BASH, $BASH_VERSION, ...

```
if [ "$BASH" ] ; then
   echo "Running in bash"
else
   echo "Running something else"
fi
```

Comment: Note that the `/proc` trick is not universal (it is Linux-specific).

Comment: echoing above reply, proc filesystem perhaps exists only on Linux.